# Did Cyclops go to jail after the Avengers vs. X-Men?

Tags: avengers-vs-x-men, marvel

I'm trying to figure out if the Avengers vs. X-Men storyline is in the current Marvel universe or a separate timeline/universe.  Did Cyclops go to jail after the Avengers vs. X-Men? Are the teams "blended" now?

Answer (score 4):

According to the entry from Wikipedia on [Avengers vs. X-men](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Avengers_vs._X-Men) "In the aftermath, Cyclops is placed under arrest and Captain America puts together a new team of Avengers."  This is all in the current 616 Main Marvel Universe

Answer (score 1):

Yes, Cyclops went to jail after the events of Avengers vs X-Men. However he was subsequently broken out by Magneto, Danger and Magik in Avengers vs X-Men - Consequences.